# The image is rotated 180 degree after saving

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a problem about loading image to a form using MFC/C++ technology.
However after the image is loaded, it's rotated 180 degree on form.
I tried saving the image, here some code line for testing
`strGrfFlt = dlgFile.GetPathName();  SECImage* pImage = OpenImage(strGrfFlt); pImage->SaveImage(strGrfFlt);` 
I found that, it's also rotated 180 degree on window.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4BH8.png)
A few other images I tested that it's ok
I'm wondering if there's any problem with this image.

Does anyone know this error, please help me.
Many thanks.

Comment: Digital cameras typically store the camera's rotation in EXIF data or similar, so that image display tools can rotate it accordingly to reproduce the correct "up" direction from the actual image sensor data. My guess is that this SECImage class does not support that.